# Which Event to include in User Plugin that fires on Save button in Plugin manager?

Tags: plugin, user, plugin-events

My user plugin, "Myplugin", works. I have extra parameters in the plugin that can be set in the Plugin Manager (Menu: Extensions / Plugins / MyPlugin). Those are stored in the database when using the Save button. Joomla core handles this.

Now I want to encrypt some values, before they get stored in the database. I suppose, this should be done on an event that fires when using the Save button in the Plugin Manager.

I've been trying to search for an event, but without success. Which one must I include in my plugin or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: `onExtensionBeforeSave` is the event that you need.

Comment: That event is not called on a User plugin...

Comment: Can you not just write an accompanying system plugin which will get triggered by that event?

Comment: That is an idea. It is far from ideal but it is a solution. Thanks.